# MySQL - One to Many Query with results in separate columns

Tags: mysql, database, one-to-many

I have a table with structure which is similar to the format mentioned below.
They look like this

Book

```
| ID | Title |
| 1  | A     |
| 2  | B     |
```

Book_Collaborators

```
| COLLAB_ID |BookID | Type      |
| 1         | 1     | Author    |
| 2         | 1     | Editor    |
| 3         | 1     | Publisher |
```

Collaborators

```
| ID | Title |
| -- | ----- |
| 1  | D     |
| 2  | E     |
| 3  | F     |
```

I need results in the following format where the details such as author, editor and publisher are displayed in different columns.

Just to be noted that some times details might not be present in Book_Collaborators table

```
| BOOK ID   | Title  | Author | Editor | Publisher |
| --------- | -----  |------  | ------ | --------- | 
| 1         | A      | D      | E      | F         |
```

I have come up with this query but I don't want to join multiple times to the same table

```
select book.id as BookId, c.title as Author,c1.title as Editor
from Book book
left join Book_Collaborators bc on (book.id=bc.book_id and bc.type='Author')
left join Collaborators c on (bc.COLLAB_ID=c.id)
left join Book_Collaborators bc1 on (book.id=bc1.book_id and bc1.type='Editor')
left join Collaborators c1 on (bc1.COLLAB_ID=c1.id)
```

Comment: When book_collaborator tables will full empty then what do you want to show? As per your given data for book 2 there is no info in book_collaborators table. Do u want to show book 2 with null value in author, editor and publisher field.

Comment: Yes, I want to show NULL value in case collaborator data doesn't exist for a Book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show all book info either it has related value in book_collaborator table or not. If only related value needed then use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. As book id is unique in book table so aggregate function is used at title column for avoiding it to add GROUP BY clause.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT b.id BOOK_ID
     , MAX(b.title) Title
     , MAX(CASE WHEN bc.btype = 'Author' THEN c.title END) Author
     , MAX(CASE WHEN bc.btype = 'Editor' THEN c.title END) Editor
     , MAX(CASE WHEN bc.btype = 'Publisher' THEN c.title END) Publisher
FROM Book b
LEFT JOIN Book_Collaborators bc
       ON b.id = bc.book_id
LEFT JOIN Collaborators c
       ON c.id = bc.collab_id
GROUP BY b.id
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=069dc205f176968d61d462ad3cad7568